# How to create a class for a type of object?

Tags: objective-c, oop

Ok, I'm still getting used to how Objective-c works.

Lets suppose I'm making a todo list app.  Instead of just reading from a plist and loading it into a table, some people say that you should create a class, lets call it `ToDo` that contains for example:

```
NSString *title;
NSString *description;
```

Ok, fine.  Now how would I use such a class to load my data from a plist or something?  I don't understand how creating a little class helps.  Can anyone explain to me how this works?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question that is hard to answer well without knowing your background. You should have a read through [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Articles/ooOOP.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005149-CH8-SW1) and try to come back with more specific questions.

Comment: I understand the concepts, but I just can't formulate the question as well as I'd like.  Basically some people create a **reusable** todo class.  Kinda makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "reusable"?

Comment: In the sense that it isn't just a static class.  It has properties and it is created multiple times for multiple todos.

Comment: Once you define a class, you can then create multiple instances of the class. Each instance is a separate object with data of its own. That's Object-Oriented Programming.

Comment: Right!  Please elaborate in an answer or something.  Thanks old man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just creat a subclass of NSObject with NSCoding protocol(if you want to save it in a plist)

Example: *.h file

```
@interface ToDo : NSObject <NSCoding> {

    NSString            *title;
    NSString            *toDoDescription;

}
@property (copy) NSString           *title;
@property (copy) NSString           *toDoDescription;

@end
```

Example: *.m file

```
@implementation ToDo

@synthesize title, toDoDescription;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self setTitle:@"none"];
        [self setToDoDescription:@"none"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [toDoDescription release];
    [super dealloc];
}

// Next two methods and coding protocol are needed to save your custom object into plist

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        title = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"] copy];
        toDoDescription = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"toDoDescription"] copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:toDoDescription forKey:@"toDoDescription"];
}

@end
```

Use NSKeyedArchiver to covert your object into NSData. And then add it to a plist.